# Data-frame columns into list of lists using Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A data-frame and I want to transform it.

```
data = {'Number': [536, 578, 36, 468, 86], 
'Content' : ["Banana","Apple","Orange","Mango","Grape"],
'Quantity': [1, 2, 5, 2, 6],
'Origin': ["TX","TX","OP","OP","OP"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

The ideal result is something like:

```
OP    [[36,5,Orange], [86,6,Grape], [468,2,Mango]]
TX             [[536,1,Banana], [578,2,Apple]]
```

I tried:

```
df.groupby(['Origin', 'Number', 'Quantity'])['Content'].apply(list))
```

also:

```
df.groupby(['Origin', 'Number', 'Quantity'])'Content'].apply(list)).groupby(level=0).apply(list)
```

But not getting nearer.

What's the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.groupby('Origin').apply(lambda x: x.drop('Origin', axis=1).values.tolist())
```

Output:

```
Origin
OP    [[36, Orange, 5], [468, Mango, 2], [86, Grape,...
TX                  [[536, Banana, 1], [578, Apple, 2]]
dtype: object
```

If you want the list in the correct order, you would need to re-order your columns. For example:

```
(df[['Number', 'Quantity', 'Content']]
    .groupby(df['Origin'])
    .apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
)
```

And you get:

```
Origin
OP    [[36, 5, Orange], [468, 2, Mango], [86, 6, Gra...
TX                  [[536, 1, Banana], [578, 2, Apple]]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
df.drop('Origin',1).apply(list,1).groupby(df['Origin']).agg(list)
Out[80]: 
Origin
OP    [[36, Orange], [468, Mango], [86, Grape]]
TX                [[536, Banana], [578, Apple]]
dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you for the sharing of knowledge. Would you mind I choose the earlier one (also easier to digest) for answer?

Comment: @MarkK no problem ~!